# Why I can not play google drive video using Exoplayer?

Tags: android, exoplayer

I can play any mp4 video using Exoplayer in my Android project. But the video uploaded to Google drive or blogspot site is not playing in Exoplayer. Is there any solution to this problem?

Here's the code I'm using:

```
public class MagicalExoplayer extends AppCompatActivity {

 private AndExoPlayerView andExoPlayerView;

 //   private String TEST_URL_MP4 = "https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4";


 //Blogger site video link but can't play this video
 private String TEST_URL_MP4 = "https://bestmedicalpdf.blogspot.com/2020/05/mrcpwiz-free-mrcp-mcqs-mrcpwiz-your.html";

 private String TEST_URL_HLS = "https://content.jwplatform.com/manifests/yp34SRmf.m3u8";

 private String TEST_URL_MP3 = "https://host2.rj-mw1.com/media/podcast/mp3-192/Tehranto-41.mp3";

 private int req_code = 129;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_magical_exoplayer);

     andExoPlayerView = findViewById(R.id.andExoPlayerView);

     findViewById(R.id.local).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             selectLocaleVideo();
         }
     });

     findViewById(R.id.mp4).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             loadMP4ServerSide();
         }
     });

     findViewById(R.id.hls).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             loadHls();
         }
     });

     findViewById(R.id.mp3).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             loadMp3();
         }
     });

 }

 private void loadMp3() {
     andExoPlayerView.setSource(TEST_URL_MP3);
 }

 private void loadHls() {
     andExoPlayerView.setSource(TEST_URL_HLS);
 }

 private void loadMP4ServerSide() {
     andExoPlayerView.setSource(TEST_URL_MP4);
 }

 private void selectLocaleVideo() {
     if (PublicFunctions.checkAccessStoragePermission(this)) {
         Intent intent = new Intent();
         intent.setType("video/*");
         intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
         intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
         startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Video"), req_code);
     }
 }

 private void loadMP4Locale(String filePath) {
     andExoPlayerView.setSource(filePath);
 }

 @Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
     super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
     if (requestCode == req_code && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
         Uri finalVideoUri = data.getData();
         String filePath = null;
         try {
             filePath = PathUtil.getPath(this, finalVideoUri);
             loadMP4Locale(filePath);
         } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
             Toast.makeText(this, "Failed: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }
     }
 }

 private class ChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
     private View mCustomView;
     private WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback mCustomViewCallback;
     protected FrameLayout mFullscreenContainer;
     private int mOriginalOrientation;
     private int mOriginalSystemUiVisibility;

     ChromeClient() {
     }

     public Bitmap getDefaultVideoPoster() {
         if (mCustomView == null) {
             return null;
         }
         return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext().getResources(), 2130837573);
     }

     public void onHideCustomView() {
         ((FrameLayout) getWindow().getDecorView()).removeView(this.mCustomView);
         this.mCustomView = null;
         getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(this.mOriginalSystemUiVisibility);
         setRequestedOrientation(this.mOriginalOrientation);
         this.mCustomViewCallback.onCustomViewHidden();
         this.mCustomViewCallback = null;
     }

     public void onShowCustomView(View paramView, WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback paramCustomViewCallback) {
         if (this.mCustomView != null) {
             onHideCustomView();
             return;
         }
         this.mCustomView = paramView;
         this.mOriginalSystemUiVisibility = getWindow().getDecorView().getSystemUiVisibility();
         this.mOriginalOrientation = getRequestedOrientation();
         this.mCustomViewCallback = paramCustomViewCallback;
         ((FrameLayout) getWindow().getDecorView()).addView(this.mCustomView, new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(-1, -1));
         getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(3846 | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE);
     }
 }
```

But any other mp4 video easily play.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://bestmedicalpdf.blogspot.com/2020/05/mrcpwiz-free-mrcp-mcqs-mrcpwiz-your.html is a webpage and not the url to a video or audio file.

Comment: But when i add this link in webview the video is play.